# What does "singles bubble" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> A 'singles **bubble**' will be introduced for the first time in New South Wales to provide relief to residents bracing for another month in lockdown.

I can guess what bubble mean here from the context. But using world bubble here sounds super uncommon to my ear. Could you explain that word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "single bubble" but "single**s** bubble"

"Singles" are single people.  People who don't have spouses.

A bubble is (in the context of Covid) a group of people who may make social contact with each other, but must socially distance from people in other bubbles.  When a case of covid occurs within a bubble, only those in the bubble need to isolate, not the entire community. The formation of "bubbles" is one strategy that governments and organisations have used to allow for some groups of people to meet during lockdows.

So a "singles bubble" is a "bubble" (in the above sense) for single people

Comment: it was a quote from https://www.9news.com.au/national/coronavirus-nsw-lockdown-update-singles-bubble-introduced-lockdown-extension-greater-sydney/01cb7378-db67-4d8b-8adb-725692440a97, but seems you are right. other sites used "singles". So could you explain how "bubble" is used for this purpose?  what would be other alternatives?

Comment: Yes.  9news uses "singles" too. You made a mistake when writing your question.  For "how bubble is used", see the third paragraph.  "A bubble is (in the context of Covid) a group of people who may make social contact with each other, but must socially distance from people in other bubbles."  What is unclear?  There are no alternatives  It is a technical term used during this pandemic. (The word "pod" was suggested but never took hold)

Comment: I could not find that meeing in a dictionary. Is it a new trend to use that word after the pandemic?

Comment: Now, I can also see how it figuratively is related to the bubble. as the ball of liquid.

Comment: Yes, new word coined in mid 2020, but the figurative meaning of "bubble" existed before then, meaning a "group of people who socialise together, but rarely mix with other people" Eg https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filter_bubble from 2010

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this definition from AmSlang dictionary (which seems its not online anywhere.

> bubble
>
> 1. v.   To completely zone out of a group conversation and engage in one-on-one conversation with a date or significant other while the
>    group conversation continues.    Davin and Elyse bubbled while the
>    group continued debating the existence of true love.
> 2. n.   Your personal space, the small area that is around you.    Your in my bubble, pal.